# Fixing a wobbly dining room chair

Tags: chair

I have a few wobbly dining room chairs that I would like to repair.  From my research online it states that the best solution is to disassemble the chair, scrape off the old glue, re-glue the joints and then re-assemble the chair.

The problem that I'm encountering is the back part of the chair and it appears that it is only held in with glue.  When I went to try to pry it apart with a spreader it started to rip out the wood threading underneath which I believe might impact the chair structurally.

Do you have any tips dealing with this (please see the attached pictures)?
[image: Chair]
[image: Ribbed part of the chair]

Comment: Glue is usually permanent.  You need to to find a softener or a removal solution before trying to separate wood glued together.  A well done glue joint is usually stronger than the wood, so the wood will separate in pieces before the glue joint gives way.   Adding wood screws where the wobbly pieces are might be easier.  Use pilot holes for the screws.

Comment: Which parts are wobbling? Is it the back assembly (back + back legs) where they meet the side rails?

Comment: there might be hidden screws ... take off the seat

Comment: @jsotola I mean, there are clearly at least four "not hidden" screws!

Comment: @Huesmann those are probably for the seat

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the sitting surface was fabricated with glued joints, where they left 4 corner notches for installing the legs (including the back) later. They then connected the legs to the sitting surface. These leg-to-sitting-surface connections are the ones that are probably failing.

There may have been glued dowels in addition to mechanical fasteners in these leg-to-sitting-surface connections. I would be weary of trying to disassemble things because the back legs are joined together above, so there's a good chance of 2 or more dowels to sever during disassembly. Instead you should probably add additional fasteners.

Hardwood like that tends to split pretty easily if you install screws without pilot holes. Chapter 12 of the [National Design Specification](https://awc.org/publications/2018-nds/) calls for different pilot hole diameters depending on wood density and whether the loading is shear versus tension (they say "withdrawal" instead of "tension"). I believe that there's relatively little shear demand and that your wobble maps to creep or a tension failure.

In the case of creep, simply tightening the existing mechanical fasteners will solve the problem. I feel that this is unlikely the root cause for a professionally built piece of furniture like yours. It's an easy first step, though, so retightening is worth a shot.

In the case of a tension failure in the fastener(s) you'll need to install additional screws. Removing an existing screw for examination is a good method for sizing your new screws. Assuming there was one screw, do two screws: one above the failed screw and one below the failed screw (if there's not enough space, then you can alternatively install a larger diameter screw in place of the failed one, but this presumes a pull-out tension failure instead of a splitting tension failure).

For a hardwood with oven dry specific gravity between 0.5 and 0.6 (like maple), NDS 12.1.5.2 prescribes a pilot hole with 70% of the diameter of your screw's minor diameter (the solid part's diameter, where you ignore the diameter across the tips of the threads). If the hardwood's oven dry specific gravity is greater than 0.6 (like oak), then NDS 12.1.5.2 prescribes a pilot hole with 90% the diameter of the screw's minor diameter. These pilot hole diameters will maximize the screw tension strengths, so be sure to get it right. When installing you want to just draw everything tight and then take an extra 1/4 turn (I couldn't find an authoritative source, so this "1/4 turn" is my best guess--authoritatively it's 1/2 turn for Douglas Fir plywood for what that's worth). Overtorquing will greatly reduce tension strength, so I would use an old fashioned screw driver.

Feel free to lubricate the screw with soap or wax--anybody wringing their hands about corrosion is full of it. The last thing you want is to twist off the screws before installation is complete. And shop for screws calibrated for hardwood. They tend to have finer threads than the softwood screws.

Comment: Might be TMI for a simple tightening job, but good info.  For wood agree with tight plus 1/4 and would not want over that.

Comment: @crip659, I figure that you already tried tightening any fasteners before you go through the trouble of constructing a question with images or you go searching around the internet for solutions. Thanks for some confirmation on the 1/4 turn.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I’ll be sure that I try some of the advice in this and let you know.  The back part of the chair is one piece and from what I can tell it is being held on with glue.  The part that attaches to the seat frame is a tongue and grove type connection.

Comment: @Pikestriker, I would put fasteners diagonally through those corner braces and into the interior corners of the legs. If any glue resists pulling things together, then I'd whack the leg with a rubber mallet while tightening the screws.